# Create a python script with command line arguments

Tags: python-2.7, installation

I need to create a python script which does install/uninstall.
Currently my script is able to do only install. I call it as below:

```
python ./script.py --arg1 arg2 --arg2 arg2 --arg3 arg3
```

The code snippet is as below:

```
def main(argv):
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--arg1', help='Enter arg1', dest="arg1")
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--arg2', help='Enter arg2', dest="arg2")
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--arg3', help='Enter arg3', dest="arg3")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args
```

I want to modify above script so that I should be able to execute the script as following:

```
python ./script.py --install --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2 --arg3 arg3
```

or

```
python ./script.py --uninstall
```

When I give --install as command line argument, I expect arg1, arg2 and arg3; but when --uninstall is given as command line argument then I do not expect anything else

Can I do what I intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have updated my python script as below:

```
def main(argv):
    install = sys.argv[1]
    if install == "--uninstall":
            uninstall()
    elif install == "--install" or install == "--help":
            install()

def install():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Installing/Uninstalling")
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--install', dest='accumulate', action='store_const', 
                      const=None, default=None, 
                      help='Please provide either --install / --uninstall')
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--arg1', help='Enter arg1', dest="arg1")
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--arg2', help='Enter arg2', dest="arg2")
    subparser = parser.add_argument('--arg3', help='Enter arg3', dest="arg3")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args
```

Please let me know if this is correct way of doing it? Or there is some better way?